# git worktree add renamed remote branches

Tags: git, git-worktree

### PROBLEM:

I used these commands to create a two new branches. New branch `GTEC-426-eth` was supposed to originate from `feature/eth_testing` while new branch `GTEC-426-ksz` was supposed to originate from the `feature/KSZ8851SNL_testing`.

```
git worktree add -b GTEC-426-eth ../worktrees/GTEC-426-eth feature/eth_testing
git worktree add -b GTEC-426-ksz ../worktrees/GTEC-426-ksz feature/KSZ8851SNL_testing
```

After changes were done on these new branches, they were pushed to the origin.

```
git push --set-upstream origin GTEC-426-eth
git push --set-upstream origin GTEC-426-ksz
```

Now I am checking the Gitlab graph and it seems that this did not add new branches but **renamed** the existing ones...

This is the graph from `tig` GIT client if I run it from the `GTEC-426-ksz` branch:

[image]

This is a graph of `GTEC-426-ksz` branch on Gitlab:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

---

### POSSIBLE REASONS:

I read in the `man git worktree` about `-b`:

```
 -b <new-branch>, -B <new-branch>
           With add, create a new branch named <new-branch> starting at <commit-ish>, and check out <new-branch> into the new working tree. If <commit-ish> is omitted, it defaults to HEAD. By default, -b refuses to create a new
           branch if it already exists.  -B overrides this safeguard, resetting <new-branch> to <commit-ish>.
```

I am working on Windows/WSL and I suspect that because Windows has problems with normal/capital letters it might interpreted `-b` as  `-B`... I have no other idea why this could otherwise happen...

Comment: Are you sure that the original branches were renamed and you didn't just create new branches with different names?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am sure. Check the added screenshots.

Comment: I'm not sure how you conclude that the original branches were renamed. In the second screenshot (Gitlab UI), both `feature/eth_testing` and `feature/KSZ8851SNL` are still there.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I see. Is it just that I don't know how to interpret these graphs? I don't understand why would GitLab and `tig` put my new branch on the same line as the branch from which this new branch originates.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now. **All the git graphs use horizontal space saving if possible.**

Let us take a look at the Graph from GitLab from earlier:

[image]

Here, it really looks like branch `feature/eth_testing` was renamed to `GTEC-426-eth` but this is not the case. Branches `feature/eth_testing` and `GTEC-426-eth` really are two different branches! So a normal person like me would expect this part of graph to look like this:

[image]

This looks nicer, but look how much horizontal space it takes! This is why, to save horizontal space, git draws a graph in a single line and marks the end of each branch like shown in the first image. It will continue to do this until it can - until there is another commit on branch `feature/eth_testing`. When this happens, it will be forced to move `GTEC-426-eth` branch out of the way and draw a graph like this:

[image]

I tested this by creating additional commit on `feature/eth_testing` and graph really behaved like just described:

[image]

**NOTE:** I also had to use `tig --all` instead of simply `tig` to see all the branches.